# addTextChangedListener как interface

Tags: java, android, listener

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему я могу реализовать интерфейс View.OnClickListener вот так

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    //.............
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    //.............
                    break;
            }
    }
}
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

А вот с addTextChangedListener я не могу так сделать, то есть я не могу написать так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.addTextChangedListener
```

Хотя и setOnClickListener и addTextChangedListener - это тоже Listener.
Я новичёк, и не могу понять в чём разница между двуми лисенерами. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: не можете потому что ошибка возникает? Если да, то текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: ок, `View.OnClickListener` - это интеофейс. А что такое `View.addTextChangedListener`? Это точно интерфейс или таки метод? Если это метод, то от метода наверное нельзя унаследоваться.

Comment: Вам надо не addTextChangedListener имеплементировать, а TextWatcher

Comment: Ок, задам вопрос немного по-другому:
как сделать один обработчик addTextChangedListener для несколько EditText?
Если по примеру OnClickListener, то в методе OnClick есть параметр View v, который я потом могу обрабатывать в switch case. 
Да, можно сделать implements TextWatcher, но у его методов нет View v, и придётся вешать addTextChangedListener на каждый каждый элемент EditText отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать TextWatcher класс:

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private View view;
    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String text = editable.toString();
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.name:
                model.setName(text);
                break;
            case R.id.email:
                model.setEmail(text);
                break;
            case R.id.phone:
                model.setPhone(text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

в него вы передаете view текстового поля и в `afterTextChanged` разбираете в switch-case:

```
someEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(someEdittext));
```

вот есть подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts). Если вам нужно проверять изменился ли текст по сравнению с тем что был ранее установлен в поле, то можно в качестве tag его присвоить и потом проверять:

```
view.getTag() != text
```